# Should I use value objects creating them via factory method and have only getters or just write DTO's with constructor and getters/setters?

Tags: php, api, libraries, value-object

I've been using the APIs of a ticketing service which returns arrays of data more or less complex based on the entrypoint called. In order to simplify my life when consuming such API I wrote some classes to map locally arrays to objects so I can:

- get suggestions from the IDE when coding instead of checking always the docs to see which values are available in the responses.
- use type hinting for those objects

Now, for fun, I'd like to cover all cases of the API and opensource the library so maybe someone could benefit from it.

**Question is**: should I use value objects creating them via factory method and have only getters or just write plain old objects (data objects?) with constructor and getters/setters?

Consider that main use in **my** case is just reading data from the API and convert it to objects. However there might be some usages which would work the other way around creating objects locally, converting to arrays and POSTing to API. Maybe there should be 2 libraries?

Comment: The short answer to your question is "it depends on whether your objects need to be mutable.  For this sort of use case, folks usually opt for DTO's  and don't bother with the complexity of a factory creating immutable objects, but it depends on what your specific needs are.